# identityserver4 protect public api

Tags: api, security, jwt, identityserver4

I am using identity server 4, I followed the tutorial, so I have an api, mvc client, console client, and js client.

I saw this blog too, which is probably close to what I need:
https://medium.com/all-technology-feeds/testing-your-asp-net-core-webapi-secured-with-identityserver4-in-postman-97eee976aa16

what I need is an api, where clients can access data, but first, they need authenticate.

we also have the console client, which is also close to what I need.

The only issue with this examples is that in both cases client knows the secret. But in our case multiple clients should use the same api, and if they all have the same secret, they can log in on behalf of each other, but I don't want to have different secrets.

So what I think I could do is to create an api which takes username and password, and returns the token. But I am not sure if this is the right way to do things? This feels like a resource owner flow, which is not supposed to be used for client facing APIs if I am correct. But in that case, how should I go it?

thanks

Comment: why don't you want each client to have different secrets?

Comment: @Richard, ok so in this case "client" in a company, they use the same api, but they should get different data, the data available to them. And I guess I can have 1 secret/resource. But I want multiple client-companies to use the same resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that there is some confusion. Allow me to give a short summary. First the [terminology](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/intro/terminology.html):

- A **user** is a human that is using a registered client to access resources.
- A **client** is a piece of software that requests tokens from IdentityServer - either for authenticating a user (requesting an identity token) or for accessing a resource (requesting an access token). A client must be first registered with IdentityServer before it can request tokens.
- **Resources** are something you want to protect with IdentityServer - either identity data of your users, or APIs.
- [Client credentials](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html#client-credentials): The simplest grant type and is used for server to server communication - tokens are always requested on behalf of a client, not a user.

---

Now about authentication. The client requests tokens at the IdentityServer endpoint. When you use a client in combination with the *client credentials* flow, then you'll need a clientid + secret. Where secret is really secret and should be known to the client only. You can't use the same secret here. Seems logical when compared to users, they don't share the same password either.

This is close to the *resource owner* flow, however a client cannot login as a user. For that you'll need another flow, like the *hybrid* flow. In that case the client logs in *on behalf* of the user. The difference is the presence of the "sub" claim (the id of the user) in the token.

The client in this case is your app: console or mvc. The first only supports client credentials where the secret is mandatory, the second supports a hybrid flow, where secret may be omitted:

> In certain situations, clients need to authenticate with
>   [identityserver](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/secrets.html#secrets), e.g.
>
> - confidential applications (aka clients) requesting tokens at the token endpoint
> - APIs validating reference tokens at the introspection endpoint

The Api is your resource, that you want to protect. The Api never authenticates a user or client. This is done by IdentityServer. It only verifies the token (using the IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation package). For that it has its own secret that should only be known to the Api.

In order to grant the client access to the resource you'll need to add the scope to the client in the configuration of IdentityServer. The client is then allowed, not required, to request a token that grants access to the resource.

Again, the Api has nothing to do with authentication. It is also not bound to one client. Multiple clients can access the resource. All you have to do is add the scope to each client that should have access to the resource.

So there is really nothing against it that clients and resources know their secret. You don't have to change anything. All you have to do is choose the appropriate flow.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, however, I think you haven't answered the question. Let me rephrase:
we have 3 applications:
- The idenitity server (token server)
- The API
- A console application (for example)
The token server and the api runs on my server, but the console application is maintained by other people outside of my company (I'll call them client-companies, as users is not really a good word here)
Now the problem is, the console application has to know the secret. But I can't share the same secret for multiple client-companies.

Comment: The secret in case of client credentials is very much like a password in case of a user. Is it a problem that the user knows his own password?

Comment: I think it is. First, can I have 1 resource, multiple secrets, a different one for each client-companies? Probably I can't. But even if I could, I still don't think it is good.
For example, a client-company has 10 developers maintaining the application, they all know the secret, they fire one of them, who can still log in, because he knows the secret, and they can't change the secret all the time.

Comment: Each client has its unique clientid. When you think in terms of instances, each instance is unique. So the Mvc client is one instance, but the console app has multiple instances, for each client. Make sure the clientid is not hardcoded, and create a unique secret for each client.

Comment: I think this is a very dark scenario. If you suspect faul play then you (as owner of the resource) can revoke access at any time by changing the keys. You can add code to add security to your api, like whitelisting. As a side note, developers should never have access to the production environment.

Comment: Why can't they change the secret all the time? It's the responsibility of the company to keep the credentials at a safe place. It is your responsibilty to secure the resource.

Comment: So I need to create a client for each client-company, and provide them a way to change the secret?
This is still strange to me. for example, the developers of the client-company should not be able to log in on behalf of eachother, but if they know the secret, they can

Comment: The client app is one piece of code that you can copy for each client company. You can create a setup where the client company has to configure the id / secret. You can also add a small configuration program to update the settings. As an alternative you can keep the clientid / secret in a vault or so. When the company wants to develop the client app themselves, then you'll only need to give them clientid / secret.

Comment: Developers don't login and can't login on behalf of eachother. The console client app uses client credentials to login. There are no users in this flow, there is no "sub" claim. The console client shouldn't have access to personal data without having the user to login. Things change in case of an Mvc website, which is one client app and an optional secret. The client doesn't have access to the resource, the user has. The client can request the scope, but the user has to give consent (when enabled). Only then, on behalf of the user, the client can access the resource, including the "sub" claim.

Comment: ok, we are getting there :) Thanks a lot :)
What if I want a console client, each company has its own, but the company has users, and each user should get different data back?

Comment: also, within the resource code, and I identify which client is accessing it? As different clients should get different results.

Comment: When a user is involved you should add a UI that allows the user to login. Optionally ask for consent and save the refresh token: `Since access tokens have finite lifetimes, refresh tokens allow requesting new access tokens without user interaction.`. http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/refresh_tokens.html Using the refrtesh token the client app can now login without any further user interaction. You can set an absolute expiration or sliding expiration for the refresh token.

Comment: For identifying the client, you can add a claim to the client (ClientClaims) with information about the client. E.g. type="http: //mycompany.com/id" and value "10".